# Yii2 framework GETTING STARTED. После инструкций по работе с gii появились ошибки

Tags: php, yii, yii2, gii

Я начинающий. Сделал все точно по гайду, и уже долгое время не могу отдебажить ошибку.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html Вот сам гайд.

Честно говоря, даже не знаю какую информацию сюда нужно скинуть, чтобы вы точно смогли понять как исправить ошибки. Так как я пока не совсем разобрался с фреймворком.

По идее весь код должен был сгенерироваться gii, поэтому само появление ошибки меня очень удивило. Синтаксис языка пока плохо знаю, поэтому не понял где объявлять эту переменную.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите что у вас в файле controllers/CountryController.php

Answer (score 3):

Ну, батенька, вы бы язык выучили бы сначала, а потом за фреймфорки брались бы.
Ошибка здесь, заключается в том, что не объявлена переменная, которую вы пытаетесь крутить в цикле. Объявите ее, вероятно это будет выборка из базы, и все будет работать. Ее надо передавать из контроллера в помощью метрода render. Там где return $this->render('index', ....